Add a hard return to an event.value fields
I have created a PDF Form (in Foxit). One field is multiple selection list (Using CTRL+Click to select more than one). The output field is a Text field using the following in the Calculate tab, Custom calculation script:
var SelectedRelCap=this.getField("RelatedCap").value;
event.value=SelectedRelCap;

It works BUT I would like each SelectedRelCap (list item) on its own line.
I tried adding \n at the end (before the ;) but then nothing works.
event.value=SelectedRelCap\n;

I have tried putting ' around the \n too.
